# Change file creation date

Tags: python, linux, file, date

Can I change creation date of some file using Python in Linux?

Comment: Same question for Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4996405/321973

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Linux and Unix file system stores :

> File access, change and modification time (remember UNIX or Linux never stores file creation time, this is favorite question asked in UNIX/Linux sys admin job interview)

[Understanding UNIX / Linux file systems](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-filesystem-inodes.html)

Comment: Note: there is `st_birthtime` on some Unix systems such as FreeBSD.

Comment: you can extract crtime from ext4 fs using [xstat function](http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/)

Comment: It's no longer true that Linux no longer supports creation time.  See my answer below.

Comment: The thing is, while ext4 do [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features) this *crtime* attribute, [AFAIU](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-preserve-crtime-creation-birth-time-when-copying-from-windows-ntfs-to-linux-ext4-4175625229/#post5829217) that's not supposed to hold the same meaning than in other (or just Windows?) file systems. It's a specific property of the inode, not the contents itself. And I think for this reason there isn't any API to change or set it (which was actually what OP had asked).

Answer (score 17):

You can use [os.utime](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.utime) to change access and modify time but not the creation date.

Comment: >Set the access and modified times
But i need creating date.

Comment: Quote from the docs on that function: "Set the access and modified times of the file specified by path." .. so you can't use it to set the creation date.

Comment: It would be nice to add that there the concept of file creation date does not exist in most native *nix filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a UNIX expert, so maybe I'm wrong, but I think that UNIX (or Linux) don't store file creation time.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [os.utime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.utime)

```
os.utime(file_path,(new_atime,new_mtime))
```

Comment: it doesn't change *creation* time as [@Nadia Alramli's answer explicitly says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/887564/4279).

Answer (score 2):

It's no longer true that Linux doesn't support creation time.  See:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/470134/how-do-i-find-the-creation-time-of-a-file

Note this specific answer to view C-code that displays the field:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/980750/116108

If the author of that post can help I might be able to create a wrapper with ctypes to modify it from Python.

Comment: did you ever created it? I would like to modify ctimes in Linux