# How do I change the file creation date of a Windows file?

Tags: python, windows, file, date, time

How do I change the file creation date of a Windows file from Python?

Comment: *modification*, *access* times could be changed by `os.utime()` http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.utime

Comment: @Sebastian: thanks for the links. i looked at the SO questions, they said there no platform-independent way to do it as for example linux doesn't store file creation times

Comment: @David: hah nice, i'll remember that. what do you do for comments?

Comment: @Claudiu: I've posted it for readers who search google for `"python change file date windows"`. Your question is the second link.

Comment: Same question for Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/q/887557/321973

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Yak shaving](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Y/yak-shaving.html) for the win.

```
import pywintypes, win32file, win32con
def changeFileCreationTime(fname, newtime):
    wintime = pywintypes.Time(newtime)
    winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
        fname, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)

    win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime, None, None)

    winfile.close()
```

Comment: If you get an ImportError and wonder where you could find `pywintypes` (as I did): http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Comment: @Delta's solution is much simpler.

Comment: I like this "yak shaving" indeed this feels like what I am trying to do to support the Wintendo operating system. :)

Comment: `GENERIC_WRITE` requests data access that's not required here and either may not be granted by the file security or may lead to a sharing violation if an existing open doesn't share write-data access. The operation should only request `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` metadata access, for which no data-access sharing is required, e.g. `hfile = win32file.CreateFile(fname, ntsecuritycon.FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, 0, None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)`.

Answer (score 42):

I did not want to bring the whole `pywin32` / `win32file` library solely to set the creation time of a file, so I made the [`win32-setctime`](https://github.com/Delgan/win32-setctime) package which does just that.

```
pip install win32-setctime
```

And then use it like that:

```
from win32_setctime import setctime

setctime("my_file.txt", 1561675987.509)
```

---

Basically, the function can be reduced to just a few lines without needing any dependency other that the built-in [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) Python library:

```
from ctypes import windll, wintypes, byref

# Arbitrary example of a file and a date
filepath = "my_file.txt"
epoch = 1561675987.509

# Convert Unix timestamp to Windows FileTime using some magic numbers
# See documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167296
timestamp = int((epoch * 10000000) + 116444736000000000)
ctime = wintypes.FILETIME(timestamp & 0xFFFFFFFF, timestamp >> 32)

# Call Win32 API to modify the file creation date
handle = windll.kernel32.CreateFileW(filepath, 256, 0, None, 3, 128, None)
windll.kernel32.SetFileTime(handle, byref(ctime), None, None)
windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
```

For advanced management (like error handling), see [the source code of `win32_setctime.py`](https://github.com/Delgan/win32-setctime/blob/master/win32_setctime.py).

Comment: This code would be more useful if the meanings of the magic numbers were explained. My guesses are:
 - epoch is time in seconds? Since when? Maybe it doesn't matter?
 - 10000000 is a conversion factor between seconds and WIndows' 100 ns time units
 - 116444736000000000 is, well, I have no idea. It seems to be a time span of ~369 years, but I can't really tell.

Comment: @BruceDawson This comes from the Microsoft documentation: [How To Convert a UNIX time_t to a Win32 FILETIME or SYSTEMTIME](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167296/how-to-convert-a-unix-time-t-to-a-win32-filetime-or-systemtime).

Comment: Thanks. That helps give context to the meaning of some of the magic numbers. It would still be good to document them in your answer, including the still unexplained 1561675987.509 number, which I guess is just a randomly selected time?

Comment: @BruceDawson Sure, I added some comments to the code snippet. ;)

Comment: The project on GitHub should be updated to use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` and raise exceptions via `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`. This (1) isolates it from other packages that use the global library loader `ctypes.windll`, which caches loaded libraries, which cache function pointers, and (2) reliably captures the thread's last error value in C immediately after the FFI call.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ErykSun, I will make the update whenever I have some time (otherwise feel free to open a PR). Please, can you explain me why should I explicitly call `ctypes.get_last_error()` while raising a `WinError()`? Reading the documentation, I thought `GetLastError()` was automatically called anyway.

Comment: Using ctypes to call `GetLastError()` via FFI leaves a lot of executed code between the original FFI call and the `GetLastError()` FFI call -- since Python is an interpreted scripting language. Loading the DLL with `use_last_error=True` automatically configures all function pointers created from it (e.g. `kernel32.CreateFileW`) to use a thread-local variable to set and capture the value of `GetLastError()` in C before and after the FFI call. `ctypes.get_last_error()` returns this thread-local last error value, and `ctypes.set_last_error(error_code)` sets it.

Comment: @ErykSun I think I got it, thanks a lot for the clarification! I will update `win32-setctime` as soon as possible.

Comment: This is super useful, thank you for making and explaining it.

Answer (score 11):

### My simple <s>and *clear*</s> [`filedate`](https://github.com/kubinka0505/filedate) module might accommodate your needs.

*Advantages:*

- Very simple interface
- Platform independent
- Fancy string dates support
- *Date Holder* utility

---

### Installation

```sh
pip install filedate
```

---

### Usage

```py
import filedate
Path = "~/Documents/File.txt"

filedate.File(Path).set(
    created = "1st February 2003, 12:30",
    modified = "3:00 PM, 04 May 2009",
    accessed = "08/07/2014 18:30:45"
)
```

Answer (score 8):

> **install pywin32 extension first** https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/

```
import win32file
import pywintypes

# main logic function
def changeFileCreateTime(path, ctime):
    # path: your file path
    # ctime: Unix timestamp

    # open file and get the handle of file
    # API: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__CreateFile_meth.html
    handle = win32file.CreateFile(
        path,                          # file path
        win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,       # must opened with GENERIC_WRITE access
        0,
        None,
        win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        0
    )

    # create a PyTime object
    # API: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pywintypes__Time_meth.html
    PyTime = pywintypes.Time(ctime)

    # reset the create time of file
    # API: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__SetFileTime_meth.html
    win32file.SetFileTime(
        handle,
        PyTime
    )

# example
changeFileCreateTime('C:/Users/percy/Desktop/1.txt',1234567789)
```

Comment: Why is it so hard to find out that `win32file` is part of `pywin32`? Google left me high and dry, which meant none of the other answers were at all useful; they assumed you already had it installed. Thank you for the helpful hint at the top of your answer.

Comment: P.S. Anybody who needs a timestamp from a `datetime` object can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7852855/5987

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more robust version of the accepted answer.  It also has the opposing getter function.  This addresses created, modified, and accessed datetimes.  It handles having the datetimes parameters provided as either datetime.datetime objects, or as "seconds since the epoch" (what the getter returns).  Further, it adjusts for Day Light Saving time, which the accepted answer does not.  Without that, your times will not be set correctly when you set a winter or summer time during the opposing phase of your actual system time.

The major weakness of this answer is that it is for Windows only (which answers the question posed).  In the future, I'll try to post a cross platform solution.

```
def isWindows() :
  import platform
  return platform.system() == 'Windows' 

def getFileDateTimes( filePath ):        
    return ( os.path.getctime( filePath ), 
             os.path.getmtime( filePath ), 
             os.path.getatime( filePath ) )

def setFileDateTimes( filePath, datetimes ):
    try :
        import datetime
        import time 
        if isWindows() :
            import win32file, win32con
            ctime = datetimes[0]
            mtime = datetimes[1]
            atime = datetimes[2]
            # handle datetime.datetime parameters
            if isinstance( ctime, datetime.datetime ) :
                ctime = time.mktime( ctime.timetuple() ) 
            if isinstance( mtime, datetime.datetime ) :
                mtime = time.mktime( mtime.timetuple() ) 
            if isinstance( atime, datetime.datetime ) :
                atime = time.mktime( atime.timetuple() )             
            # adjust for day light savings     
            now = time.localtime()
            ctime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(ctime).tm_isdst)
            mtime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(mtime).tm_isdst)
            atime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(atime).tm_isdst)            
            # change time stamps
            winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
                filePath, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
                win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)
            win32file.SetFileTime( winfile, ctime, atime, mtime )
            winfile.close()
        else : """MUST FIGURE OUT..."""
    except : pass
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
os.utime(path, (accessed_time, modified_time))
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

At least it changes the modification time, without using win32 module.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure this only changes the file modification time and access time, not the file creation time, as the OP desires.

Comment: On XP at least it sets the creation time.

Comment: Doesn't do anything on XP or Win7 for me, the atime sets accesstime and mtime sets modifiedtime, neither sets creationtime.

Answer (score 3):

This code works on python 3 without
`ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime`:

```
wintime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(newtime).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
    fname, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)
win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime)
winfile.close()
```

Comment: Error using python 3: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @Vlad it's an error using incorrect import statements. The object is datetime.datetime as in my example, not datetime.datetime.datetime as you're trying to use it.

Comment: you're right - I've change the import statement but now the error is `a float is required` for `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(newtime)`.  It would be great to have this work in python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works on Python 3.5 and windows 7.  Very easy. I admit it's sloppy coding... but it works.  You're welcome to clean it up.  I just needed a quick soln.

```
import pywintypes, win32file, win32con, datetime, pytz

def changeFileCreationTime(fname, newtime):
    wintime = pywintypes.Time(newtime)
    winfile = win32file.CreateFile(fname, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                   win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | 
                                   win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | 
                                   win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                   None, 
                                   win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                   win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                                   None)

    win32file.SetFileTime(      winfile,  wintime,  wintime,     wintime)
    # None doesnt change args = file,     creation, last access, last write
    # win32file.SetFileTime(None, None, None, None) # does nonething
    winfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_tz = pytz.timezone('Antarctica/South_Pole')
    start_date = local_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(1776,7,4), is_dst=None)
    changeFileCreationTime(r'C:\homemade.pr0n', start_date )
```

Comment: For directories: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998814/createfile-getfiletime-setfiletime !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a date instead of an epoch you can grab this code. I used win32-setctime and attrs packages so firstly install:

```
pip install win32-setctime
pip install attrs
```

Then you can run my code, remember to update FILEPATH, DATE, MONTH and YEAR.

```
from datetime import datetime

import attr
from win32_setctime import setctime

FILEPATH = r'C:\Users\jakub\PycharmProjects\date_creation_change\doc.docx'
DAY, MONTH, YEAR = (9, 5, 2020)


@attr.s
class TimeCounter:
    """
    Class calculates epochs
    """
    day = attr.ib(converter=str)
    month = attr.ib(converter=str)
    year = attr.ib(converter=str)

    def create_datetime(self):
        date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(r'{}/{}/{}'.format(self.day,
                                                             self.month,
                                                             self.year), '%d/%m/%Y')

        unix_start = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
        return (date_time_obj - unix_start).days

    def count_epoch(self):
        days = self.create_datetime()
        return days * 86400


@attr.s
class DateCreatedChanger:
    """
    Class changes the creation date of the file
    """
    file_path = attr.ib()

    def change_creation_date(self):
        epoch_obj = TimeCounter(day=DAY,
                                month=MONTH,
                                year=YEAR)
        epoch = epoch_obj.count_epoch()
        setctime(self.file_path, epoch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    changer = DateCreatedChanger(FILEPATH)
    changer.change_creation_date()
```

Answer (score 0):

A small solution without dependencies inspired by [Delgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56805533/14720622).
It supports unix timestamps up to nano precision (like the values returned by `os.stat(...).st_ctime_ns` as an example).
Modified, accessed and created timestamps are supported.
Unpassed/noned parameters are being ignored by the Win32 api call (those file properties won't be changed).
*It requires python 3.10 for the multi-type hints used on the parameters. Just remove the hints if you want it to work for older python versions.*

```python
from ctypes import wintypes, byref, WinDLL, WinError, get_last_error


def __unix_ts_to_win_filetime(self, timestamp: int | None) -> wintypes.FILETIME:
    if not timestamp:
        return wintypes.FILETIME(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF)

    # difference in ticks between 16010101 and 19700101 (leapseconds were introduced in 1972 so we're fine)
    _EPOCH_OFFSET_TICKS = 116444736000000000
    # truncate timestamp to 19 decimals or fill it up with zeroes
    timestamp = int(str(timestamp)[:19].rjust(19, '0'))
    timestamp_in_ticks = int(timestamp / 100)
    # add epoch offset to timestamp ticks
    timestamp_in_ticks += _EPOCH_OFFSET_TICKS
    # convert to wintypes.FILETIME by filling higher (32-bit masked) and lower number (shifted by 32 bits)
    return wintypes.FILETIME(timestamp_in_ticks & 0xFFFFFFFF, timestamp_in_ticks >> 32)

def __set_times_on_file(self, path: str, created_timestamp: int = None, access_timestamp: int = None, modify_timestamp: int = None) -> bool:
    created_timestamp = self.__unix_ts_to_win_filetime(timestamp=created_timestamp)
    access_timestamp = self.__unix_ts_to_win_filetime(timestamp=access_timestamp)
    modify_timestamp = self.__unix_ts_to_win_filetime(timestamp=modify_timestamp)

    # Win32 API call for CreateFileW and SetFileTime
    kernel32 = WinDLL("kernel32", use_last_error=True)
    hndl = kernel32.CreateFileW(path, 256, 0, None, 3, 128, None)
    if hndl == -1:
        print(WinError(get_last_error()))
        return False

    if not wintypes.BOOL(kernel32.SetFileTime(hndl, byref(created_timestamp), byref(access_timestamp), byref(modify_timestamp))):
        print(WinError(get_last_error()))
        return False

    if not wintypes.BOOL(kernel32.CloseHandle(hndl)):
        print(WinError(get_last_error()))
        return False

    return True
```

Usage example

```python
if __set_times_on_file(path='C:\Windows\Temp\foo.bar', created_timestamp=1657101345298000000):
    print("file timestamps could be set")
else:
    print("file timestamps could not be set")
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a straight answer for python exactly, so i am leaving an answer for anyone searching how to modify the dates for a [directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987026/createfile-always-returns-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-open-directo) (or a file, thanks to the answers in this thread).

```
import os, win32con, win32file, pywintypes


def changeCreationTime(path, time):

    try:
        wintime = pywintypes.Time(time)
        # File
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            winfile = win32file.CreateFile(path,
                                           win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                           win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ |
                                           win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE |
                                           win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                           None,
                                           win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                           win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                           None)
            win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime, wintime, wintime)
            winfile.close()
            print(f'File {path} modified')
        # Directory
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            windir = win32file.CreateFile(path,
                                          win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                          win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE |
                                          win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE |
                                          win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                          None,
                                          win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                          win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                                          None)
            win32file.SetFileTime(windir, wintime, wintime, wintime)
            windir.close()
            print(f"Directory {path} modified")
    except BaseException as err:
        print(err)
```

Example:

```
# Create a folder named example and a text file named example.txt in C:\example
changeCreationTime(r'C:\example', 1338587789)
changeCreationTime(r'C:\example\example.txt', 1338587789)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the answer from Claudiu replace following lines

```
import pywintypes, win32file, win32con
wintime = pywintypes.Time(newtime)
```

as follows, in order to change also milliseconds of the file creation

```
import datetime, win32file, win32conimport 
wintime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(newtime)
```