# CreateFile GetFileTIme SetFileTime

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having trouble using GetFileTime and SetFileTime 
when it comes to directories.  Specifically I think my problem is
that I am new to the WinAPI and I don't think I'm getting the
HANDLE correctly.

There are 2 scenarios.

In the first, I just need a handle to get the file or directory
timestamps (create,access,mod).  I'd like to make this handle in a safe and flexible way.
Don't want to be too generous in the parameters.

In the second, I need a handle that will allow me to modify the file or direcotry
timestamps.  I'd also like to create this handle with the minimum rights but in flexible and dependable way.

By flexible I mean that in both scenarios I need the code to work both localy, in a network share, and in a multi-threaded app.  The multi-threaded part is not  necessary because my app will not make multiple handles on the file/dir but it is possible that some other app running in the background will.

```
//QUESTION 1:
//I do this when I just need a handle to **GET** some attributes like dates.
//(here I just need a handle to get info I am not modding the item).
//Am I using the correct params if I need it to work in a 
//local + networked environment and also in a multi-threaded app???
h1 = CreateFile(itemA, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (h1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

    return 0;
}
//QUESTION 2:
//The above works for local files but not local dirs.
//How can I get the above to work for dirs? (Same environment considerations).


//QUESTION 3:
//I do this when I just need a handle to ***SET*** some attributes (like timestamps).
//(here I need a handle that allows me to modd the items timestamp).
//Am I using the correct params if I need it to work in a 
//local + networked environment and also in a multi-threaded app???
hItemB = CreateFile(itemB, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (hItemB == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    return 0;
}
//QUESTION 4:
//The above works for local files but not local dirs.
//How can I get the above to work for dirs? (Same environment considerations).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer #2: To use `CreateFile` to get a handle to a directory, you need to use the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag. Using your example:

```
h1 = CreateFile(itemA, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
```

I would guess this would work for Answer #4 as well, but I haven't tried it to confirm.

Comment: Thanks Joel, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS worked.  I have a hard time deciphering the meaning of FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS in the MS docs.  What exactly is this?  Hopefully someone can also critique the other flags I'm using.  I should also note that ACCESS timestamp is a little flaky with above code.  It doesn't seem to be set reliably.

Comment: @user440297 - FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS is really for backup software to access files for the purpose of making a backup. In that way, it feels like a bit of a hack to use it to make CreateFile get a handle to a directory. However, from what I've seen in MSDN, that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again Joel Rondeau.  What is the difference between FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE and FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS (both part of dwFlagsAndAttributes)?  I am interested in getting attributes and setting attributes... so what I'm doing is backup centric. Should I be using FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE and if so why and how?          http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Short answer is that one is an attribute and the other is a flag, so they aren't really related. FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE is just a file attribute (can look at using Explorer). Turning on this attribute just marks the file as needing to be archived. Best example of this I can think of is Source Control. TFS will set the archive attribute on file checkout and clear it on checkin. So, no, I don't think you necessarily need to be using the archive attribute.

Comment: For anyone wondering, here's the reference to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx#DIRECTORIES) calling for the use of FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS when opening directory handles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example on how to set a directory's date based on a DOS date timestamp.

```
int Directory_SetDosTime(char *Path, unsigned int DosDateTime)
{
    FILETIME LocalTime, FileTime;
    HANDLE Handle;
    SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;


    DosDateTimeToFileTime((DosDateTime >> 16), DosDateTime, &LocalTime);
    LocalFileTimeToFileTime(&LocalTime, &FileTime);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&FileTime, &SystemTime);

    Handle = CreateFile(Path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

    if (Handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //Unable to open directory
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (SetFileTime(Handle, &FileTime, &FileTime, &FileTime) == 0)
    {
        //Unable to set directory time
        CloseHandle(Handle);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(Handle);
    return TRUE;
}
```