# How to get directory file handle in C#?

Tags: c#, file, winapi, directory

I need to call native Win32 API from .NET code which required file/directory handle. How do I get a handle for the directory?

To get a file handle I use the following code:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open...))
{
    var handle = stream.SafeFileHandle;
    /// Call Win32 API here
}
```

1. How do I get a handle for a directory?
2. Is there any better approach for getting the handle for files? I fill like using FileStream is confusing for those who will read this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Directory Using CreateFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198420/open-directory-using-createfile)

Comment: @Klaus Gütter The answer says that administrative privileges are required. My app runs with minimum user permissions. Also File.Open() / FileStream.SafeFileHandle does not require admin privileges. So I guess there should a way to obtain a handle without admin permissions.

Comment: Directory handles are different. See description of FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS in [CreateFile documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew). Also this is relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-a-handle-to-a-directory

Comment: @Klaus Gütter So to call GetFileTime() Win32 API for a file I do not need admin privileges. But to call it for a folder I need admin privileges. I am scratching my head.

Comment: Im confused, you dont want to use FileStream and want to use raw api calls, so why not just use raw api calls to get the handle ? Also unless you have spent a lot of time in win32 api, i doubt the code will be more readable. Especially since you will need to PInvoke everything

Comment: Also if you want to get the file time just call `FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("path"); fi.CreationTime;` It couldn't be easier to read

Comment: Whether or not administrator privileges are required depends on the directory you want to open. The `GetFileTime` document mentions that the `hFile` must have `GENERIC_READ` access (use `CreateFile` with `dwDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ` and `dwFlagsAndAttributes = FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`). If you do not have `GENERIC_READ` for the directory Access, you may need elevated permissions to get handle from `CreateFile`.

Comment: @Drake Wu - MSFT Thank you! This brings us much closer to the point. I need to call CfUpdatePlaceholder(). And I finally found params for opening a folder and calling this function without admin privileges!

Comment: You could feel free to share your own answer and [accept yourself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)