# CreateFile always returns error 5 (Access is denied) when trying to open directory for reading

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

I want to open directory handle so that I can watch that directory for file changes. I have written a simple class wrapper over the winapi, and this is how I set the directory path before starting the watch:

```
bool SetDirectory(const std::string& dirname)
{
  HANDLE dirHandleNew = CreateFile(
    dirname.c_str(),
    // Just normal reading
    FILE_GENERIC_READ,
    // Share all, do not lock the file
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
  );

  if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != dirHandleNew)
  {
    _dirHandle = dirHandleNew;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    _dirHandle = 0;
    RLog("Cannot open directory %s for filesystem watching. Win error: %d (%s)", dirname.c_str(), GetLastError(), GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    return false;
  }
}
```

The error is always:

```
Cannot open directory D:\tools for filesystem watching. Win error: 5 (Access is denied.)
```

I tried different folders on different volumes to see if this is an actual permissions issue, but it doesn't seem like it. `D:\tools` in my PC is a normal folder, accessible to all users. But as I said, I tried other folders too, error is always the same.

I also tried to instead open with `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` (I only need dir listing) and `GENERIC_READ`. Error was still the same.

Maybe the `CreateFile` parameters are wrong?

Comment: [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw) doesn't take a file handle, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my program watch for file modification in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c)

Comment: Did you try the one mandatory flag for "opening" a directory handle with CreateFile ? Namely `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` ? `CreateFile` clearly documents this: *"You must set this flag to obtain a handle to a directory. A directory handle can be passed to some functions instead of a file handle."*. Not that it matters; I suspect a directory handle acquisition is the Y of what appears to be an XY problem.

Comment: because win32 errors very bad design. you not got access denied. you got `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` if call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`. because you not add `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`. simply win32 convert `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: @AlanBirtles `FindFirstChangeNotification` not enough functional, compare `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. must not be used

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thi is not a duplicate of the linked question at all. As you observed yourself, in this question I am concerned about opening the directory, not watching the files. RbMm's comments are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Don't use FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL!

To open a directory with CreateFile, Use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` instead of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`.

You should specify `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter.

This should work now.