# date/time attributes in zip format

Tags: unix, zip

I am trying to find out whether **file and directory** creation date is stored into zip file. From what I can see using `zipinfo` is only modification time.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers) for the Zip file format explains that all files must have a **modification** date/time field. There is **no** creation date/time field. However, you can store whatever metadata you like using the [*Extra* field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Extra_field), but this is not standardized whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in another answer, by default ZIP file can only store the modification date of a file. Any additional metadata, including file creation date, *can* be stored in `extra` field. And it IS standardized to some extent, so different archivers can understand each other.
Some of the most commonly used extra blocks are described in [PKWARE's official ZIP file specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) and the most complete documentation can be found in [Info-ZIP's extra field description](https://fossies.org/linux/unzip/proginfo/extrafld.txt).

However, on most UNIX(-like) systems [there is no creation time at all, with some of them providing it with OS-specific extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887557/change-file-creation-date). It may be that the file you was inspecting had been created in OS with no creation time or the archiving software used didn't bother to support it on UNIX.